# Cannot define PRIMARY KEY Constraint on nullable column when column is already NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table called `Cases` that has information about interviews such as `IV_Date`, `IV_Length`, `Interviewer`, etc. I also have a field within `Cases` called `Case_Code` (a `varchar`) which is a six-character (three letters + three numbers) identifier; e.g. "ABC123" or "ZZZ999." There is a foreign key on `ContactID` (an `int`), which points to a `Contact` table. I have created a computed column which is the PRIMARY KEY of this `Cases` table, called `CaseID`. `CaseID` is simply a concatenation of `Case_Code` and `ContactID`. So, `ContactID` "25" working on case "ZZZ999" is given a `CaseID` of "ZZZ99925". Neither `Case_Code` nor `ContactID` accepts nulls, so `CaseID` obviously does not. When setting up `CaseID` I created it as NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY, and used the formula "[Case_Code] + CONVERT([varchar], [contactID], 0)". I thought everything was working fine but when I try to rearrange any fields in the SQL Studio table design view, I get thrown this error:

```
'Cases (dbo)' table
- Unable to create index 'PK_Cases_1'.  
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'Cases'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.'
```

I do not understand why I'm getting this error, since all NOT NULL columns in my table contain data. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit with code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cases](
    [ContactID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Case_Code] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Assigned_To] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LEK_Interviewer] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Case_Notes] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [IV_Status] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [IV_Quality] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [IV_Date] [date] NULL,
    [IV_Length] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Total_Honorarium] [money] NULL,
    [Currency] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Last_Update] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CaseID]  AS ([Case_Code]+CONVERT([varchar],[contactID],0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Cases_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CaseID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Are you using the SSMS GUI to "rearrange fields"?

Comment: Yes I am I apologize for not mentioning that. Right click on 'dbo.Cases' > 'Design'.

Comment: If you are "moving" a column (changing its ordinal position), I think SSMS does some gymnastics behind the scene.  Something like creating a temp table with the desired column positions/order, copying data from the orig table to the new table, dropping the orig table, and renaming the new table.  This can have some undesired side effects.  I suspect something similar is happening to you in your situation.

Comment: I've noticed that I get that error when I try to move ANY field via the GUI. Even if the fields moved have nothing to do with the PK or even FK. I'm not sure as to why, but your idea does make sense.

Comment: Never, never rearrange columns or use the GUI to change the table structure. It recreates the table from scratch and then moves the data into it. This is something you would NEVER want to do on production. Further you should do all database changes through source controlled scripts so that you can move the changes to production easily.

Comment: PLease show us the script for your table, It is impossible to fuigre out the problem with existing data.

Comment: @HLGEM what exactly do you mean by the table's script?

Comment: Please generate the create script of your table and don't forget to mension the script of the objects that are related to your table (Cases) : Index, Primary Key, Computed column, Views...

Comment: No Idea how to format this, sorry!<br/>
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cases](
[ContactID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Case_Code] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[Assigned_To] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Case_Notes] [varchar](max) NULL,`
[IV_Status] [varchar](100) NULL,
[IV_Quality] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
[IV_Date] [date] NULL,
[IV_Length] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Address] [varchar](100) NULL,
[City] [varchar](100) NULL,
[State] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Zip] [varchar](25) NULL,
[Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CaseID]  AS ([Case_Code]+CONVERT([varchar],[contactID],0))` PERSISTED NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Cases_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERE`

Comment: @user put it inthe question and mark it as code

Comment: @HLGEM I have put the code in the OP, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

A primary key cannot be applied on a column with a null constraint (nullable). When a table is created, by default every column is nullable.

So first off all we have to remove the null constraint and apply a NOT NULL constraint on the column. To do this execute the following query

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name alter column column_name int NOT NULL
```

After that you can apply a primary key on that same column. To do this execute the following query

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_name)
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

I bumped into this, too.  You can create a PK on a calculated field, as long as it's marked NOT NULL, but the SQL Server table design interface does not handle this situation; it seems to mark all calculated fields as NULLable when modifying a table.

First, I strongly recommend that you always create and modify your tables with scripts, not the GUI.  Doing so gives you a record of what you have and what changes you've made; you can run them to recreate your database as of any point in time.  As HLGEM mentioned, you can also keep these scripts in source control.  Having these scripts makes it easier to do things which are difficult to do with the GUI, and as you've discovered here, they make it possible to do things which are impossible in the GUI.

Within the table designer, delete your PK.  You should then be able to save the table, effecting the reordering of fields you wanted to achieve.  Next, you need to drop and recreate the calculated field, and finally you can recreate your PK.  E.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE Cases DROP COLUMN CaseID
ALTER TABLE Cases ADD CaseID AS (Case_Code + CAST(ContactID AS CHAR(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE Cases ADD CONSTRAINT CPK_Cases PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CaseID)
```

If you have any indices which reference the calculated field (other than the PK, which we've already dropped), you'll need to delete them before you can drop the calculated field.  Be sure to re-create them after, of course.

Finally, while Dean did not support his assertion that calculated fields are bad for PKs, he is correct that it would be simpler to put your PK on { `Case_Code`, `ContactID` }.  You could then stop persisting `CaseID` (if you even need it all) and save yourself a little disk space.

Comment: awesome to have a real answer to this, rather than "cannot reproduce"...  it would be great if you added the info from the comment in the Question that this may be associated with trying to "insert columns" in the GUI before making this change

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
Alter table tablename
add column datatype identity(1,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use computed column as a primary key, very bad idea. In your case, just define the PK on both CaseCode and ContactID columns. In the designer, select both columns, right-click and choose "set prinary key" from the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the response @dean. Why should you never use a comp column as the PK? Why is this a bad idea?

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a bug in the SQL Server Management Studio. The easiest approach is to make your changes using the designer. Then generate the change script using:

```
Right-click > Generate Change Script...
```

Copy the generated SQL or save it to a file. Then, add "NOT NULL" to the computed column in the CREATE TABLE statement and run the SQL file